# wscript cscript with javascript to use COM with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, com, itunes, wsh

OS: windows 10 
 Node: v6.9.4 
iTunes 12.5.5.5

I'm trying to write a node.js app that communicates with itunes, it will do a lot of things and i want to capture the response and show in a web page.

what i'm trying to do right now to understand this wscript thing is run a node file, that it will keep running to output on the 'change song' event some info about the tack.

After i did some research i made to a point, but now i'm stuck.
I have no knowledge on windows ecosystem coding and is in this part that i'm struggling

searching the web i found this solution.

i don't find why i can on cmd use cscript o wscript but inside the .js file i need to use wscript

```
/* itunes open and playing a song */
var itunes = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");

var currentTrack = itunes.CurrentTrack;

WScript.Echo("name: " + currentTrack.Name + " artist: " + currentTrack.Artist);
```

open a cmd, go to that folder, and run

```
cscript /nologo myItunesScript.js 
/* /nologo prevent to show some default cmd text*/
```

the program will run, output the music playing and it will close itself

If i do the same thing with wscript i don't know why but it show a popup window with the result instead of showing on the cmd screen.

On this page http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/main.html show a lot of things that i can do and even work with events.

I didn't find any app on npm that does some magic and makes my life easier.

So if someone can give some north, i will appreciate a lot.

**EDIT:** It is possible to connect to "iTunes.Application" without WScript from node? 
If don't, is possible to listen for events from the output o WScript? (like in socket.io, you connect to someting and keep listening for things)

Comment: `cscript.exe` is the command line version of the WSH *(Windows Scripting Host)* while `wscript.exe` is the GUI version. They are one and the same thing, just with different output. Example the code `WScript.Echo "Hello"` in `cscript.exe` will output to the command line while the same line executed with `wscript.exe` will output to a popup message.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't clear I probably shouldn't of answered.
This answer specifically address this from the question;

> *If i do the same thing with wscript i don't know why but it show a popup window with the result instead of showing on the cmd screen.*

You may be confusing what `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` are.

Both programs are the WSH *([Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), also confusingly known as WScript)*.

- `cscript.exe` - The command line version
- `wscript.exe` - The Windows GUI version

Both run VBScript but output the results differently, here is a simple example to demonstrate.

The following script will output the phrase `Hello World`;

```vb
Dim output: output = "Hello World"
WScript.Echo output
```

Using `cscript.exe` the output is;

```
>cscript //nologo "test.vbs"
Hello World
```

Using `wscript.exe` the output is;

```
>wscript //nologo "test.vbs"
```

[image: Popup WScript Window]

Comment: ok, but can you give me a example on how to run from node and keep runing to listen for events.

Comment: @MateusSilva if that is what you intentionally meant to ask try updating the question, at the moment it doesn't say anything like that. I simply tried to answer *"If i do the same thing with wscript i don't know why but it show a popup window with the result instead of showing on the cmd screen."*, which I have done.

Comment: its on the question "what i'm trying to do right now to understand this wscript thing is run a node file, that it will keep running to output on the 'change song' event some info about the track."